# Fix the position of Divs

Tags: html, css

Lengthy One, but only the explanation part.I am working in ASP.NET and the page came out just as I wanted.But somehow, the same code in the fiddle is not.http://jsfiddle.net/yucRt/

```
.logodiv
{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#495C6E;
 height:7%;
 color:white;
}    
.menu
{
 background-color:#335E89;
 height:5%;
}
.content
 {
 border:1px solid #C2C8BD;
 margin:0 0.6% 0.6% 0.6%;
 height:84%;
 border-radius:3px;
 border-top:none;
 padding-top:1%;
 padding-left:1%;
 padding-right:1.1%;
}
.panelsearch
{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
 height:6%;
}
 .panelgrid
{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
 height:57%;    
}
.paneledit
{
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
 height:34%;
}
```

Hence I have also uploaded the image.[image]

All the 3 divs (with red borders) are placed inside the content div(white border), as you can see.

WHAT I WANT (but failed to acheive):

(1). The logodiv and menudiv should be fixed with vertical scroll.

(2). The searchpanel & gridpanel should be of the height as they appear in pic,and should not compress with lesser content.

(3). The edit panel should expand a/g to its content and so should the ContentDiv.

WHAT I TRIED:

Put both the logodiv and menudiv inside

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0"></div>.
```

Though it keeps them fixed, it overwrote the specified heights for those 2 divs inside, meaning, both the logodiv & menudiv are now of the same height.

Achieved(3) by removing heights for contentdiv and editpanel and adding

```
overflow:hidden
```

for both. But if the page has no text in any of the 3 panels, all of them compress.

Comment: Put the resulting html in the fiddle, not the asp source code.

Comment: I belive, you were unable to view the fiddle page. Same with me. Is it a bug. I was able to view for the first time but not now. Happened with other questions in forum here. By the way, the code in fiddle is only HTML.

Comment: I can view it fine.  It has tags like `<asp:Panel>`.  If you're having trouble with it, open an Incognito window in Chrome and do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your Html like this and for the CSS you can see the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yucRt/2/).

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="logodiv">
    LOGO DIV
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        MENU DIV
        </div>
        <div class="content">
             <div id="pnlSearch" class="panelsearch">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server">
        Search Panel
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <div id="pnlGrid" class="panelgrid">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlGrid" runat="server">
        Grid Panel
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <div id="pnlEdit" class="paneledit">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlEdit" runat="server">
        Edit Panel
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: :Thank you very much. It worked. I see that you have given min-height for the 3 red divs. I just want them to be in % instead of px, cos this might vary with the monitor/screen size. right? Only px is working but not %. why is it so

Comment: % was not working because the code was based on px.Now look at it.Its base on % and its working.http://jsfiddle.net/yucRt/5/

Comment: Thank you again. I just added width:100% and z-index:1 to the menu class as it was overlapping the logodiv.